# Why is next_sibling not working as expected in html tree?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying some web-scraping stuff with `beautifulsoup4`, but for some reason `next_sibling` doesn't work as I expect it to? (or maybe I'm expecting it to work differently)

Anyway, here is what I'm working with

```
html="<!DOCTYPE html>\
  <html>\
  <head>\
  <title>Page Title</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
  <h3><b id='boldest'>Lebron James</b></h3>\
  <p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p>\
  <h3> Stephen Curry</h3>\
  <p> Salary: $85,000, 000 </p>\
  <h3> Kevin Durant </h3>\
  <p> Salary: $73,200, 000</p>\
  </body>\
  </html>"

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tag_object=soup.h3

tag_sibling=tag_object.next_sibling

print(tag_sibling)
```

`tag_object` for me is the line with the `<h3><b id='boldest'>Lebron James</b></h3>`,
so when I call `.next_sibling` I expect it to move down the tree to `<p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p>`.
It doesn't do that however.

Instead it only moves down the tree from the first `<h3>` if I call `.next_sibling.next_sibling`?
Why do I have to call it twice?

Is my understanding of `.next_sibling` wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

##### What happens?

You are not wrong it works that way you expect under special circumstances, but there is one main issue, `next_sibling` has not to be a `tag` and you can see it very well if you print your `soup`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head> <title>Page Title</title> </head> <body> <h3><b id="boldest">Lebron James</b></h3> <p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p> <h3> Stephen Curry</h3> <p> Salary: $85,000, 000 </p> <h3> Kevin Durant </h3> <p> Salary: $73,200, 000</p> </body> </html>
```

It will work well if your tags are not seperated by any text, linebreaks or other characters:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='<h3><b id="boldest">Lebron James</b></h3><p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p><h3> Stephen Curry</h3><p> Salary: $85,000, 000 </p><h3> Kevin Durant </h3><p> Salary: $73,200, 000</p>'
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.h3.next_sibling

->
<p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p>
```

##### How to fix?

Trying to get the next `tag` you should use `find_next_sibling()` instead of `next_sibling` or `find_next_sibling(name, attrs, string,**kwargs)` to get a special one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="<!DOCTYPE html>\
  <html>\
  <head>\
  <title>Page Title</title>\
  </head>\
  <body>\
  <h3><b id='boldest'>Lebron James</b></h3>\
  <p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p>\
  <h3> Stephen Curry</h3>\
  <p> Salary: $85,000, 000 </p>\
  <h3> Kevin Durant </h3>\
  <p> Salary: $73,200, 000</p>\
  </body>\
  </html>"

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.h3.find_next_sibling()

->
<p> Salary: $ 92,000,000 </p>
```